# Custom J4 Component Problems with Multilingual Associations: Edit Associations

Tags: custom-component, multilingual

I've on the way to create my first native J4 Component by using Astrid's Tutorial ([Link](https://blog.astrid-guenther.de/en/der-weg-zu-joomla4-erweiterungen/)) - I've already figured out that some of the code parts are not fully J4 conform, but i was able to "update" my code where it was needed (JForm usage for example).

But on the step with the Multilingual Associations: Edit Associations i'm stuck. All is working so far an item can be associated when doing so from inside the component but when trying to use Components >> Multilingual Associations and go into the edit view of an item the page keeps reloading till the browser crashes.

I've already tried 3 times to undo my changes added in this chapter and do it again without success. It might be just a silly mistake from my side somewhere in the codebase but what i've seen so far is that Astrid's Code examples are truly 1-1 based on the J3 solution and might not work in current J4.2 anymore?

Can someone check my Repo and give me a hint what might be the problem of this "reloading" inside the Multilingual Associations Component. Branch (associations_implemented) Ready to install can be found here: https://github.com/marcorensch/company_partners/tree/associations_implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because your form view does not render the ID field. Associations script expects an input element with `jform_id` ID and the ID of the content item as the value. Since you're using hardcoded field names, adding this to the layout should work for you:

```
<?php echo $this->getForm()->renderField('id'); ?>
```

You can change field type in the form definition to `hidden` if you don't want it to be visible to users.

Comment: OMG that was quite simple - Thanks Sharky!